# bounded PDA and context-free languages

Tags: automation, pushdown-automaton, context-free-language

> How can we prove that:
>
> *Class of linear bounded PDA languages ∼ Class of CFLs*

I know that for a linear bounded PDA there is a constant k such that the stack size for w is at most k|w|. I also read about PDA's and CFL's and know that pushdown automata are essentially finite automata with a stack as
storage and a grammar G = (V, T, S, P) is said to be context-free if all productions
in P have the form
A → x

How can this be used to show that they are equivalent?